# Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'sampledata' in 'field list'

Tags: codeigniter

I have a project in codeigniter where i taking some data through form. and the database i have used phpmyadmin. I think i have writte all correct code but there database error in my webpage and it is difficult to find out.

As there are similar questions but they didn't solve my problem.

**user.php**(controller)

```
    public function website()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        if($this->form_validation->run('website_validation'))
        {
           $post = $this->input->post();
          
           $this->load->model('Uploadmodel');
           if($this->Uploadmodel->websiteinsert($post['firstname'],$post['lastname'], $post['email'],$post['whatsapp'],$post['buissness']))
           {
            echo'<script>alert("Submitted Successfully")</script>';
           }

           else
           {
            echo "not succesfully";
           }
           
          return redirect('user/viewmainoffer');
        }
        else
        {      
                $this->load->view('user/index');
        }
        
    }
```

**Uploadmodel.php**(model)

```
 public function websiteinsert($array)
    {
        $this->db->insert('website',$array);
    }
```

**offer.php**(view)

```
<?php echo form_open('user/website'); ?>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">First name</label>
    <?php echo form_input(['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter your first name','name'=>'firstname','value'=>set_value('firstname')]); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Last name</label>
    <?php echo form_input(['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter your last name','name'=>'lastname','value'=>set_value('lastname')]); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
      <?php echo form_input(['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter your email','name'=>'email','value'=>set_value('email')]); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress2">Your Whatsapp number</label>
    <?php echo form_input(['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>' your whatsapp number','name'=>'whatsapp','value'=>set_value('whatsapp')]); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
  <label for="inputAddress2">Your business</label>
   
    <?php echo form_input(['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Your Business like Blog or anything','name'=>'buissness','value'=>set_value('buisness')]); ?>
  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       
        <?php echo form_submit(['value'=>'Get your website','class'=>' btn-lg btn btn-primary btn-block','type'=>'submit']) ?>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**the error i have got**

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'o' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `website` (`o`) VALUES ('')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/blog/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Thankyou

Comment: Your model is expecting an array and when you call it, you are passing in a number of parameters. So you have to fix that. You need to read - https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is that you don't supply the correct array to your model Uploadmodel, which is waiting for an array, while you are sending 4 different strings.

the correct approach is to send the array, which you could do like this:

```
if($this->Uploadmodel->websiteinsert($post)){
  // etc.
}
```

or if you your $post has more elements than you want to insert you could also:

```
if($this->Uploadmodel->websiteinsert(array($post['firstname'],$post['lastname'], $post['email'],$post['whatsapp'],$post['buissness']))){
  //etc.
}
```

or use `unset($post['foo'])` to get rid of $post() elements you don't want to insert